# CSS Radial Inner Shadow for Background

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to modify the background of a Wordpress template. I have an image attached with repeat-x option. I want to add a radial inner border over that image. Is it possible?

Here is the current background:

```
body {
background: #18191b url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x center 0;
color: #e9e9e9;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-moz-box-shadow` and `-webkit-box-shadow`:

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
```

And you can also use `box-shadow` to aply it to Internet Explorer

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this solution does not work in my case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SamAnila how about using `box-shadow`?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correct you need this. `box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd inset;`

More about box-shadow you can find out here: [The 'box-shadow' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-box-shadow)

Comment: Thank you, this actually works, but I still have a problem. It display the inner shadow only on the visible screen area. If I scroll down, I can see strange border of shadow at around 200px over the bottom of the page, and the bottom of the page is without shadow. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know your website structure. Here's a quick demo on how I see things. Hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/QEZnw/17/